# .htaccess rewrite advanced rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like a .htaccess rewrite rule, but I can't figure out how to make it.

Examples

www.example.com/index.php => www.example.com/index.php

www.example.com/folder/profile.php => www.example.com/profile.php

www.example.com/folder => www.example.com

A rewrite rule that can serve files from a specific folder at top level, while still serving the top-level files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here u go! try this

EDIT: made changes to exclude index.php!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/$1 [L]
```

i do the same for my Zend Framework projects , where i route all the requests from my http://domain.com/public/ to http://domain.com/

Comment: Do you want to make example.com /index.php am exception here? I am sorry though I saw ur question , I thought you had a typo: :P

Comment: I made changes to the answer, can you try now?

Answer (score 0):

To redirect if a file does't exist, do this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [R]
```

Comment: did you include a flag, I'd recommend starting with [R]